# ¿Como pasara a PDF generado con Django y xhtml2pdf una variable para consultas específicas en modelo?

Tags: django, variables, pdf, xhtml2pdf

Estoy tratando de generar pdf con django y xhtml2pdf, mi problema viene que solo lo eh podido generar de la siguiente manera.

```
class servicio(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        personal = Personal.objects.all()
        data = {
            'personal':personal
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf("radios/servicio_radio_pdf.html", data)#Funcion en otro archivo que renderiza
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = "application/pdf")
```

Al llamar esta vista puedo generar el pdf, pero no quiero que sea pdf con datos generales, en este caso con

```
personal = Personal.objects.all()
```

Obtengo todos los datos de un modelo, pero quiero obtener datos específicos en base a una variable para hacer consultas específicas al modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Eh logrado realizar el proceso que requeria, les comparto por si alguien esta igual un tanto perdido con este tema.
Primero recomiendo investigar vistas basadas en clases de Django y su implementacion, ya que este metodo de generar el PDF las usa.

Yo llamo la vista desde un enlace, pasando como parametro la variable, por lo que el codigo de path en el archivo urls seria.

`path('servicio/<int:pk>',views.servicio_pdf.as_view(), name="ServicioPDF")`

Y desde el enlace lo redirecciono con

`<a type="button" href="{% url 'ServicioPDF' val %}" target="_blank">`

donde "val" es la variable que guarda el id para posteriormente realizar consulta en la vista, este valor es el que paso como parametro.

Posterimente en mi vista basada en clase queda de la siguiente manera

```
class servicio_pdf(ListView):
    model = Servicios
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Servicios.objects.get(id = pk)
        data = {
            'servicio':queryset,
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf("servicio_pdf.html", data)#Funcion render pdf en otro archivo
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = "application/pdf")
```

Una ves investigada la vista basada en clase y su funcionamiento se entiende, el metodo get se esta sobre escribiendo(re estructurando) en donde yo manejo un parametro que es el que recibe y que nombro con el identificador pk, el cual tomo y realizo mi consulta en mi modelo. obtenidos los datos se hace el proceso normal de enviarlos en diccionario al template y listo.